# Float fluid text div inline with image div

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to left float a div (filled with text and other divs) inline with an image with a fixed width. I have tried a host of options but I cannot get the second div to float inline.

How do I get the 'sidebbar-post-col2' to float inline with the 'featured-media' image div?

Thanks in advance

http://codepen.io/coreysimons/pen/waQEBE

CODE

```css
.post-container {
  width:40%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
  
  .post {
    height:auto;
}


.sidebar-posts .featured-media {
  width:auto;
  display:block;
}

.sidebar-posts .featured-media img {
    max-width: 90px;
 max-height: 90px;
margin-right:20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.sidebbar-post-col2 {
  float:left;
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}

.entry_author_image {
    display: inline-block;
}

.author-meta {
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    float: none;
    color: #333;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.author_location {
    padding: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.sidebar-posts .post-header h2.post-title {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar-posts .category-meta {
text-align:left;
color:#000;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top:0px;
}

.sidebar-posts .post-submeta {
    text-align: left;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
}


.sidebar-posts .post-header {
vertical-align: top;
padding:0;

}
```

```html
<div class="post-container sidebar-posts"> 
  
  
<div class="post">
  
<div class="featured-media">
<a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Crazy new GIF lookbook from Kenzo lookbook from Kenzo">
<img width="433" height="558" src="http://coreysimons.com/placeholder/placeholder-img-1.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Screen Shot 2015-07-28 at 22.45.13" /></a>
</div> <!-- /featured-media -->
   
<div class="sidebbar-post-col2">
  
<div class="post-header">
<div class="category-meta"><a href="#" rel="category tag">Feature</a>, <a href="#" rel="category tag">sidebar</a></div>
<h2 class="post-title"><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Crazy new GIF lookbook from Kenzo">Crazy new GIF lookbook from Kenzo lookbook from Kenzo</a></h2>
</div><!-- /post-header -->
  
<div class="post-submeta">
<div class="entry_author_image"><img src="http://coreysimons.com/placeholder/profile-image.png" alt="Corey Simons" width="16" height="16" /></div>
<div class="author-meta"><a href="#" title="Posts by Corey Simons" rel="author">Corey Simons</a></div>
<div class="author_location">Los Angeles</div>
</div><!-- /post-submeta -->
  
</div><!-- /sidebar-post-col2 -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="spacer" style="clear: both;"></div>
  
</div><!-- /post -->
  
  <div class="post">
  
<div class="featured-media">
<a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Crazy new GIF lookbook from Kenzo lookbook from Kenzo">
<img width="433" height="558" src="http://coreysimons.com/placeholder/placeholder-img-1.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Screen Shot 2015-07-28 at 22.45.13" /></a>
</div> <!-- /featured-media -->
   
<div class="sidebbar-post-col2">
  
<div class="post-header">
<div class="category-meta"><a href="#" rel="category tag">Feature</a>, <a href="#" rel="category tag">sidebar</a></div>
<h2 class="post-title"><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Crazy new GIF lookbook from Kenzo">Crazy new GIF lookbook from Kenzo lookbook from Kenzo</a></h2>
</div><!-- /post-header -->
  
<div class="post-submeta">
<div class="entry_author_image"><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="‘Wasted Youth’ at Thinkspace Gallery"><img src="http://coreysimons.com/placeholder/profile-image.png" alt="Corey Simons" width="16" height="16" /></a></div>
<div class="author-meta"><a href="#" title="Posts by Corey Simons" rel="author">Corey Simons</a></div>
<div class="author_location">Los Angeles</div>
</div><!-- /post-submeta -->
  
</div><!-- /sidebar-post-col2 -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="spacer" style="clear: both;"></div>
  
</div><!-- /post -->
  
  
</div><!-- /post-container -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you have to do a few things:

1) On `.sidebbar-post-col2` take off the float. You also need to add a `pixel` or `percentage` width to this div. That must be specified in order for `inline-block` to work I did `50%`for my example.

2) Then on `.sidebar-posts .featured-media` I added a `vertical-align: top;` as well as changed `display:block` to `display:inline-block`

**EDIT:**

See my **latest** JSfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/d239roug/2/

Essentially what I did was:

1) `.post` class I added `display:table`

2) On `.sidebar-posts .featured-media` and `.sidebbar-post-col2` I added `display:table-cell`

The explanation for this is that `display:table-cell` distributes the space evenly depending on how much the inner content's width takes up within the `display:table` parent DIV.

Comment: The main parent div (post-container sidebar-posts) has a percentage width, so the width of .sidebbar-post-col2 has to be fluid/100%/auto so the text fills remaining space in the div. I am not able to define a width for .sidebbar-post-col2 as it's width is fluid.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I have forked a pen that shows what I am trying to achieve http://codepen.io/coreysimons/pen/eNbObM 

That seems to be working - are there advantages to your method over my new pen?

Comment: Yes @coreysimons look at the update I just made to the answer. There is a new JSfiddle link

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind elaborating on why this is a better approach to my second pen -  codepen.io/coreysimons/pen/eNbObM ? I have not used 'display:table-cell' before so am interested in understanding the advantages.

Comment: Essentially what you have there is doing the same thing. However with your method, by floating ".sidebar-posts .featured-media img" to the left, you are taking it out of the normal document flow. As you can see, you had to put a "margin-left: 110px" on ".sidebbar-post-col2" which you could think of as a "hack" to get it far enough away from the image. With my method, it keeps everything within the normal document flow which is the most efficient way for preventing websites to break @coreysimons

Comment: Do you think you could mark the answer as correct? @coreysimons